# Newtons Law of Cooling in Forensic Science

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, exponential-function

Question goes: Law enforcement would like to know the time at which a person died. The investigator arrived on the scene at 8:15pm, which we will call $t$ hours after death. At 8:15 (i.e $t$ hours after death), the temp of the body was found to be $27.4°C$ (Degrees). One hour later, $t+ 1$ hours after death, the body was found to be $26.1°C$. Known constants are $T_s=21°C$, $T_o=36.8°C$.

At what time did the victim die?

**MY WORKING**

Formula: $T(t)=T_s+(T_o-T_s)e^{-kt}$

**1**. $T(t)=T_s+(T_o-T_s)e^{-kt} \quad \rightarrow \quad  
27.4=21+15.8e^{-kt}$

**2**.$T(t)=T_s+(T_o-T_s)e^{-kt} \quad \rightarrow \quad 26.1=21+15.8e^{-kt}$

1. $27.4=21+15.8e^{-kt}\rightarrow  
   6.4=15.8e^{-kt}\rightarrow  
   \ln(6.4/15.8)=-kt\rightarrow  
   -0.903=-kt$
2. $26.1=21+15.8e^{-kt} \rightarrow  
   5.1=15.8e^{-k(t+1)} \rightarrow 
   ln(5.1/15.8)=-k(t+1)  \rightarrow $

$-1.131=-k(t+1)$

This is as far as I have got and I believe I should be doing simultaneous equations but am totally unsure if thats correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Subtract the second from the first to get $k$; then compute $t$ from the first.

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Your work is correct but it is better to write the two starting equations as:

**1**. $T(t)=T_s+(T_o-T_s)e^{-kt} $

**2**. $T(t+1)=T_s+(T_o-T_s)e^{-k(t+1)} $

You have found the system
$$
\begin{cases}
0.903=kt\\
1.131=kt+k
\end{cases}
$$
so, substituting $kt$ in the second equation you find $k=0.228$ and , from the first, $t=3,93$ that is the time , in hours, after death.